# How to design my setter method?

Tags: java, methods

I have a method which I wrote like this:

```
void updateMyJaxb(final JAXBElement<?> jaxbElement) {

addElementtoJaxb(jaxbElement)
}


void addElementTJaxb(jaxbElement)
{
   //have to cast to myown type 
((JAXBElement<MyType>) jaxbElement).getValue().setSomeValue(somevalue);
}
```

so in essence I add some staff to JAXBElement. 
The question is : is it a good design, take a reference and change the content, ?
Will it be better to return the reference to a updated object?
Otherwise the method may not be straightforward to understand ?

Comment: Wait...which method is in question here? `updateMyJaxb` or `addElementTJaxb`? (Also, I think you have some typos in the code sample.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setters should not have any effects on the parameter they take directly.
Personally I would consider that as bad design.
If you stil want to do that I would strongly recommend you to document this behavior, because the behavior might be unexpected.

Returning the objects is also not required, since Java passes parameters (objects in general) by reference.

I would use the Adapter pattern, which takes an JAXBElement as a parameter and returns a JAXBElement.
Instead of updating the JAXBElement the adapter clones it and changes the clone and returns it.
This way no unexpected side-effect are introduced.
This pattern is also called defensive-copying.

```
private JAXBElement clone(JAXBElement o) {
    JAXBElement clone = new JAXBElement();

    clone.setName(o.getName());
    ...

    return clone;
}
```

This should do the job.

Comment: Thanks, this a good answer, I like it. the only problem in my case is that JaxbElement does not support clone(), how would i go by cloning the object then ?

Comment: Your adapter could have a private method which handles the cloning.

Comment: I am still not sure how to clone? Can I just a create a new reference and perform assignment? and then return that reference . ( I know that in that case it will still do the same thing as before, but at least it is going to look nicer? I just dont know how to clone, There is not clone method implemenented for JaxbElement.

Comment: OK I think I get it, but just wanted to double check, I would have to do clone.setXYZ(o.getXYZ()) for all attributes of the JAXBElement?right?There are four in total according to the API.

Comment: One problem here.  I can not just create  JAXBElement clone = new JAXBElement(); I need to supply QName and that will depend on the type of JAXBElement I will pass, I am working with 3 types of JAXBELements. I dont see an easy way to find out other than perhaps analyse the type of the JAXBElement which arrives in a parameters, ( this becomes messy) and the clone method is starting to become too error prone? what do you recommend. I am just worried that my clone method may introduce an error , and it will be worse.